# Give an example thatT∈ L(V) satisfies nullT∩rangeT= 0 but V is not belong to (nullT⊕rangeT)

Tags: linear-algebra

> Give an example that $T\in L(V)$ satisfies $\text{null}(T)\cap\text{range}(T)=0$, but $V$ does not belong to $\text{null}(T)\oplus\text{range}(T)$.

I only see the example of $\text{range}(T)=\text{null}(T)$ or $\text{range}(T)\cap\text{null}(T)=0$, but I have never seen this exercise's condition.

Comment: What is $\text{L}(V)$?

Comment: "$V$ does not belong to..." - do you mean "$V$ is not equal to..."?

Comment: yeah V#nullT+rangeT(direct sum)

Comment: Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for formatting math.

Comment: Thank You, I'll do it next time

Comment: Could anyone give me an example of this exercise?

Comment: @SeanChao You are using Linear Algebra Done Right, right? If so you should consider changing $L(V)$ to $End(V)$ for the set of all linear endomorphisms on $V$.

Comment: Are you going to correct your question in the light of @Bungo 's first comment? As it stands it's nonsense. While you are doing that please also add a precise statement of what $V$ is. (It matters!)

Comment: L is a linear map or linear transformation.My school provided like this

Comment: Until you are willing to correct the question I can't be sure what you are asking. I didn't ask about $L$ I asked about $V$.

Comment: Hint: $V$ will need to be infinite-dimensional. (Why?)